# Deploying MVC4 .net 4.5 website to IIS7 Forbidden 403

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

I am trying to deploy a website to an IIS webserver but I keep getting a **403 forbidden** error.  I have tried all the solutions on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5300389/cs0016-could-not-write-to-output-file-error-when-starting-an-app-in-iis-7) but to no avail so I was wondering what else could be causing the 403

When I publish a different site to the same folder with the same app pool it will run and the only difference between the 2 sites is the one that isn't working is .net 4.5 and the one that is is .net 4

Has anyone got any ideas what may be causing the site to throw a 403 - I have checked the event viewer and nothing seems to be showing up

Comment: check 4.5 version framework installed to server or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying and failing with a lot of things, I have found that it was due to the routing with MVC and adding the following line into my web config seems to have fixed it:

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"></modules>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your web.config file:

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules>
    <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" />
    <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition="" />
  </modules>
```

Also copy to the bin folder on IIS any missing DLLs it complains about (like. System.Web.Http).  Set them to copylocal=true in VS to prevent this error in future.

The other anwswer to this question (

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"></modules>
```

) runs all modules all the time.  According to this blog it's too drastic and will lead to errors and slow speeds: http://www.britishdeveloper.co.uk/2010/06/dont-use-modules-runallmanagedmodulesfo.html