# App_Code Folder Access is denied in host

Tags: asp.net

i have a source code and it run on visual studio but when i upload in my host i get error

```
Compilation Error
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS0016: Could not write to output file 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\65318181\9515d618\App_Code.2g0riqnn.dll' -- 'Access is denied. '
```

please help me.

Comment: Your host's filesystem permissions are misconfigured.

Comment: The account under which IIS App Pool is running needs permissions for that path.

Comment: Check out this Q&A: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10418669/hosting-asp-net-in-iis7-gives-access-is-denied

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["CS0016: Could not write to output file" error when starting an app in IIS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5300389/cs0016-could-not-write-to-output-file-error-when-starting-an-app-in-iis-7)